# Separating Meshes with vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter

Tags: python, vtk

I am having a hard time using vtk, especially the vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter. I feed in the output of a Marching Cubes algorithm that created a surface from a 3d point cloud.
However, when i try to set

```
filt = vtk.vtkConnectivityFilter()

filt.SetInputData(surface_data) # get the data from the MC alg.
filt.SetExtractionModeToLargestRegion()
filt.ColorRegionsOn()
filt.Update()

filt.GetNumberOfExtractedRegions() # will 53 instead of 1
```

it gives me weird results. I cannot use the extraction modes for specific regions or seed a single point, since i don't know them in advance.
I need to separate the points of the largest mesh from the smaller ones and keep only the large mesh.
When i render the whole output it shows me the right extracted region. However, the different regions are still contained in the dataset and there is no way to separate it.

What am i doing wrong?

Best J

Comment: Is your problem that you just want to figure out which of the extracted regions is the largest one? Marching cubes will create surfaces to contain any region that contains a point; you're probably ending up with surfaces around all of your outlier points as well.

Comment: I need to extract the biggest region of connected points and provide it in such way that i can use it for further analysis. Therefore all non-connected points must be removed. The outlier points do indeed lead to some outlying surfaces but these should be removed by the filter, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I had to segment an STL file converted to vtkpolydata.

If you look at the example https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/PolyDataConnectivityFilter_SpecifiedRegion , you will find they use the member function SetExtractionModeToSpecifiedRegions().

Replace you code with the following:

filt.SetInputData(surface_data)

filt.SetExtractionModeToSpecifiedRegions()

filt.AddSpecifiedRegion(0) #Manually increment from 0 up to filt.GetNumberOfExtractedRegions()

filt.Update()

You will need to render and view the specified region to figure out the index of the segmented region your actually interested in.